# Exchange a battery with capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging, charger, 5v, lamp

I have this 5 V lamp work with a internal-battery. I took the battery out and it work with the 5 V charge directly. But it flash/flick sometime.
My idea is to put a capacitor in place of the battery and keep it always on the 5 V charger/adapter.
Would it work?
Or is dangerous to put a capacitor in place of a battery and keep it plugged (keep charging)?

Comment: Welcome! _”5 V charge”_ Is that charger by any chance? It’s hard to tell for sure without knowing the internals, but your setup should probably work.

Comment: 5 V is an unusual voltage for a battery, so the circuit could expect something different as an input.

Comment: Winny , yes i mean charger .    Arsenal, i meant 5v from the charger